# Is there a problem with cx_Freeze 6.6 and winpython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm getting some issues with cx_Freeze and winpython.

As i need to freeze a python script, I've tried to use cx_Freeze (pyinstaller is not working in this case).

here the script :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from BromseButton import FolderSelect,FileSelect
import pandas as pd
from Version import Version
import ezdxf

# version du script :
version = "V0.1.2"
nom_script = "bornes"
#Vérification de la version avec la classe Version
v = Version(version,nom_script)
v.return_message()

#création de la fenêtre principale
fen = Tk()
fen.geometry("710x180")
fen.title("Insertion de bornes dans un fichier dxf - " + version + " "+ v.message)
fen.iconbitmap("index.ico")

#Placement des cadres pour structurer la fenêtre
f1=Frame(fen, bd = 1, width = 900, height= 150, bg='#DDDDDD', relief='ridge')
f1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 2)

f2=Text(fen, bd = 1, width = 20, height= 5, relief='ridge')
f2.grid(row=2, column = 0,columnspan=1,padx=4, sticky = (NSEW))
yscrollbartext=ttk.Scrollbar(fen, orient=VERTICAL, command=f2.yview)
yscrollbartext.grid(row=2, column = 0,columnspan=1,padx=4,sticky=(NS,E))
f2["yscrollcommand"]=yscrollbartext.set

doc46 = ezdxf.readfile("GABARITS/Gabarit_46.dxf")
#####################################################
# Création d'une fenêtre d'impression des versions  #
#####################################################

f2.tag_configure('big', font=('Arial', 9, 'bold'))
f2.tag_configure('versionnok', font=('Arial', 9, 'bold'),foreground="red")
f2.tag_configure('versionok', font=('Arial', 9, 'bold'),foreground="green")

# affichage de l'historique des versions
f2.insert(END,"Historique des versions \n\n",'big')

j=0
for i in reversed(sorted(list(v.scripts["versions"].keys()))) :
    if j ==0 :     
        if i==version :
            f2.insert(END, i +"\n", 'versionok')
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["date"]+"\n", 'versionok' )
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["description"]+"\n\n", 'versionok' )
        else :        
            f2.insert(END, i +"\n" , 'versionnok' )
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["date"] + "\n", 'versionnok' )
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["description"]+"\n\n", 'versionnok' )
        j+=1
    else : 
        if i==version :
            f2.insert(END, i +"\n", 'big')
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["date"]+"\n", 'big' )
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["description"]+"\n\n", 'big' )
        else :        
            f2.insert(END, i +"\n")
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["date"] + "\n")
            f2.insert(END, v.scripts["versions"][i]["description"]+"\n\n")

def action() :
    csv = csv_bornes.file_path
    rep = dest_shp.folder_path
    insert_borne(csv,rep)    
    showinfo(title="résultat final", message="Insertion des bornes terminées")

def insert_borne(csv,rep):    
    msp = doc46.modelspace()
    df = pd.read_csv(csv,delimiter=';')
    for i in df.index :        
        if df['BLOC'][i] =='46_POINT_NUMERIQUE' :
            borne = msp.add_blockref(df['BLOC'][i],(df['X'][i],df['Y'][i]),dxfattribs={'layer' : 'BOR_Pt_Numerique'})            
        else :
            borne = msp.add_blockref(df['BLOC'][i],(df['X'][i],df['Y'][i]),dxfattribs={'layer' : 'BOR_Pt_Materialise'})            
        borne.add_attrib('NumeroPoint',df['NumeroPoint'][i],(df['X'][i]+6.61,df['Y'][i]+11.18), dxfattribs={'height':5, 'layer':'TXT_Borne'})    
    doc46.saveas(rep + "/bornes.dxf")

############################
# Récupération des données #
############################
# répertoire de destination pour les fichiers shp temp
dest_shp = FolderSelect(f1,"Répertoire de destination du dxf : ")
dest_shp.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

#Fichier csv
csv_bornes = FileSelect(f1,"Fichier csv : ",[("Fichiers csv","*.csv")])
csv_bornes.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

#bouton de lancement de la fonction principale : 
valider = Button(fen, text = "Exécuter", command = action)
valider.grid(row = 6, column = 0,sticky = (NW))


fen.mainloop()
```

and setup.py :

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')


# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","numpy","pandas","ezdxf"],
            'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'GABARITS/Gabarit_46.dxf'),
            os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'index.ico')]
            }

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "bornes",
    version = "0.1.2",
    description = "Bornes!",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("test.py", base=base, icon ='index.ico')]
)
```

First try :

winpython 3.7.7 with cx_Freeze 6.1. It didn't work.
So I try step by step that the problem was with pandas library.
Searching for response I try to put 'build_exe': './/build' in the options. The creation was ok but nothing append when clicking in the exe file.

Second try :

using python 3.8.6 (official distribution) :
uprgrading cx_Freeze to the 6.6 everything is ok !
The exe file is working. Ok great, I just have to upgrade cx_Freeze version of winpython and it everything will be fine... But no...

I don't know why but I've got a recursion error :

```
File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\scripts\setup.py", line 83, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 397, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 265, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 795, in Freeze
    self.finder: ModuleFinder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 464, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder = ModuleFinder(
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 70, in __init__
    self._add_base_modules()
  File "C:\Users\bruno\Documents\WPy64-3940\python-3.9.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 82, in _add_base_modules
[...]
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 853, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
```

I've tried with winpython 3.8, 3.9, same issues...

Is that a known problem with winpython ? If there is someone to help me it will be great!

Bye!

Comment: maybe it has circular imports - file A imports B, and B imports A - and this is hidden recursion. And you have error about recursion: `maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @furas ! But before posting, I've checked this. The script is really simple and my classes also. As it's working with python 3.86 but no with winpython, I'm not sure that it come from this. 
**BUT** my class BromseButton (it was supposed to be BrowseButton...) import tkinter and the main script also, is it a really a naughty stuff ?